# Add select2 data and date format to database with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, input

I want to add some select2 (jquery plugin) input data to database ... so first I have html and html is fine:

```
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="vrsta">Vrsta aktivnosti</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="hidden" id="vrsta_rada" class="form-control select2-container select2-container-multi"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

I convert select2 data into string:

```
var data1 = $("#vrsta_rada").select2("data");

$.each(data1, function(key, value) {
  var vrsta_rada = data[key].text
});
```

and I try to add this variable `vrsta` to database with ajax/jquery/php

```
ajax:
$.ajax({
            url: "insertAkt.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: true, 
            data: { vrsta_rada:vrsta_rada}, 
            dataType: "html",

            success: function(data) {
                $('#output').html(data);
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                drawVisualization();   
            },  
        });
```

and php:

```
  try {        
                    $DBH = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
                    $STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO aktivnosti (vrsta) VALUES (:1)");

                    $STH->bindParam(':1', $_POST['vrsta_rada']);





                    $STH->execute();

                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
                echo "<p>Data submitted successfully</p>";

            }
```

in brower console I get error:

```
Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionDirection' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('hidden') does not support selection. jquery-latest.js:7546

gn jquery-latest.js:7546
x.param jquery-latest.js:7519
x.extend.ajax jquery-latest.js:8021
(anonymous function) zadaci.html:341
x.event.dispatch jquery-latest.js:5095
v.handle
```

Comment: What can be a problem here?

Comment: Is it as simple as badly formed json. try `data: {"vrsta_rada":vrsta_rada},'

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. It took some digging before I found the reason so hopefully this can save others some time. Add this function:

```
function get_type(thing){
    if(thing===null)return "[object Null]"; // special case
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(thing);
}
```

Then, just before the ajax post you insert this:

```
alert(get_type(vrsta_rada));
```

My guess is that it will say "[object HTMLInputElement]". Why does this happen? It's because the variable is out of scope for the ajax call (the var declaration is inside another function) and the global resolution for the variable then finds the input element with the same id from your dom tree.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue today and the mistake was simply that I had the variable commented out.

I needed to get the value of an element to pass to my Ajax POST function like so:

```
var value = $('#element').val();
// var tid= $('#id').val();

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'myurl,
data: {value: value, tid: tid},
})
```

However because my variable declaration for "tid" was commented out I was getting the error that type hidden cannot be selected.

Simply

Answer (score -1):

I too had similar issue, later i found out that i had not retrieved the value of the HTML element and then passed to the ajax call as a paramter value.

So I had as following as per your example:

```
var data1 = $("#vrsta_rada").select2("data");
```

here `data1` will have the complete HTML element tree not the value alone, so when it's passed in as a parameter to the ajax1 call, the ajax engine will try to retrieve the value from Hidden element which is not allowed for various reasons.

So I updated as following

```
var data1 = $("#vrsta_rada").select2("data").val();
```

Now it works fine.